# Django 1.9 + sorl-thumbnail + memcached

Tags: python, django, sorl-thumbnail

I'm configuring `sorl-thumbnail` and when memcached is running locally I get this error:

```
OperationalError at /groups/1/
no such table: thumbnail_kvstore
```

When memcached isn't running (obviously doesn't work):

```
TypeError at /groups/1/
a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'
```

What's wrong with my configuration? Why is it saying there's no `thumbnail_kvstore` table? Here are my settings variables. I tried setting the `THUMBNAIL_KVSTORE` setting but it didn't change anything:

```
CACHES = {
    'default': {
        'BACKEND': 'django.core.cache.backends.memcached.MemcachedCache',
        'LOCATION': '127.0.0.1:11211',
    }
}
THUMBNAIL_DEBUG = True
THUMBNAIL_FORMAT = 'PNG'
```

Comment: Do you have any unapplied migrations?

Comment: Hi Sorl, uses DB too and than memcached to cache this values. if you don't execute migration after adding the app to the installed apps, the tables will not be in the django configured dbms.

Comment: I have it in my installed_apps. It says no new migrations.

Answer (score 16):

If just

```
manage.py makemigrations
```

doesn't create any migrations, try

```
manage.py makemigrations thumbnail 
manage.py migrate
```

This will create migrations for thumbnail and then migrate them. It works for me. I am using Django 1.9 and sorl.thumbnail 12.3.

Answer (score 5):

I had to force upgrade sorl-thumbnail:

```
pip install --pre --upgrade sorl-thumbnail
```

https://github.com/mariocesar/sorl-thumbnail/issues/384

Comment: Hi! This helped on the migration. But my images are not displayed. It gives a 404 error when I open the image.

Comment: This worked for me on Django 1.9. The latest version has a migration for the missing table.